# I upgraded to knockoutjs 2.2.1 and jquery 1.9, koExtenalTemplates are broken

Tags: knockout.js, hottowel

I can see the infuser loading the template and setting it in templates observable but the rendering doesn't happen. It just shows 'Loading', however it calls afterRender method.
the template is like

```
<button>Refresh</button>
<nav>
  <ul data-bind='template:externalTemplate,foreach:DataArray,afterRender:callMe'></ul>
</nav>
```

When the template loads the array already have few observable objects in it. But doesn't get rendered. but if click refresh button and clean and reload the array. it renders alright.

This was working alright with ko 2.2.0 and jquery 1.8... is KoExternalTemplate broken with this update?

EDIT: 
Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a new project with HotTowel SPA template (search for this
   template in google if you dont already have)
2. Via NuGet add koExternalTemplate, which will install traffic cop and infiser as well.
3. update BundleConfig.cs to add TrafficCop,infuser and koExternalTemplate
4. create a folder names Templates under root of the project add a template file. update main js with infuser configs to point to the Templates and file pattern (if you know bit of koExternalTemplate you know what i am talking about).
5. Include the template in home/details html and launch the  app.

Result: you will only see 'Loading...' in place of your template and template doesnt get rendered.

Comment: This may be because of [this bug](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/801).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dhana – The best option is to use Durandal's `compose` binding with that view. Like this:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: 'templates/_sample.tmpl.html', activate: true }">      
</div>
```

And move the templates foler under the views folder (convention).